# Triggering a button click when going on page

Tags: javascript, button, click

Is there a way to have a user click on a link that takes them to a page and triggers a (or multiple) button click(s). I imagine this would use Js.

More info: This page wouldn't have the code in it. I imagine the code would be in the link.

Comment: Assuming that both pages are yours, and you're not attempting to direct someone to a foreign page and trigger events, then yes, there is a way, and yes, it uses Javascript. Was that your only question?

Comment: No, for obvious security reasons. You can do it if the target page is under your control (if you can add scripts to it.)

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$(button-selector).trigger('click');
```